# NodeJS : How to have multiple methods for post

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am trying to make an iteractive form using nodejs.

Here is my web page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <script>
     $('#ping-button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/process_test'
        });
    });
 </script>
    <body>
        <form action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/process_get" method="GET">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br>

        Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <br>
        <form action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/process_post" method="POST">
        Team: <input type="text" name="team">  <br>

        Player: <input type="text" name="player">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        <br><br>

        <button id='ping-button'>Ping</button>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.use(express.static('test'));

app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})

app.get('/process_get', function (req, res) {

   // Prepare output in JSON format
   response = {
       first_name:req.query.first_name,
       last_name:req.query.last_name
   };
   console.log(response);
   res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
})

app.post('/process_test', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {


   console.log("Ping");
   res.end(JSON.stringify("Ping"));
})

app.post('/process_post', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {

   // Prepare output in JSON format
   response = {
       team:req.body.team,
       player:req.body.player
   };
   console.log(response);
   res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
})



var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

so i have two forms and a button. The first form is tied to the `process_get` method, the second form is tied to the `process_post` method and the button is tied to the `process_test` method.

both of the forms give expected results. When i click the button, it goes to the `process_post` method instead of the `process_test`

why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the Ping `button` submits the form to `/process_post` is because it is inside the form, and the click handler is not set due to errors.

If you open the console in your browser you will see `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. This is because you're using `$` in your code, but you include jQuery much later in the page. This you can fix by loading jQuery prior to your `script` tag.

Once that is done you will notice that the button still does not work. This is because the `script` inside `head` is executed before the rest of the document is done, ie. the `body` contents is not there yet, and `$('#ping_button')` will find nothing. This you fix by wrapping you code inside `$(document).ready(function() { // code here });` so it is executed once the whole page is loaded.

Still, clicking the button will send you to `/process_post` because the click event is not stopped in your click handler. Return false or use `e.preventDefault()` to disable the browser default action.

All this combined the `head` section (that was missing) will become

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ping-button').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/process_test'
            });
            return false;
        });
    }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Rest of your page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perfect! thanks a lot :) now it makes much more sense